# Equivalent of InputStream and OutputStream in .net core c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sockets, tcp, stream

**EXAMPLE**

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, post);
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
```

**How to organize threads in C# in a similar??**

**My thoughts on this**

```
var client = new TcpClient(host, port);
NetworkStream outputStream = client.GetStream();
NetworkStream inputStream = client.GetStream();
```

Comment: Are working directly on TCP Level? Or do you actually want to use a higher level protocol?

Comment: `NetworkStream` is fully duplex, you can use the same stream for reading and writing. Don't forget `using` to dispose your objects

Answer (score 0):

[There is a constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-net-sockets-networkstream-ctor(system-net-sockets-socket-system-io-fileaccess)) for network stream which takes a socket and file access modifier, so read only or write only, as arguments. Example:

```
new NetworkStream(socket, FileAccess.Read);
```